# MySql statement Error: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

`**Help beginner level**
**here is the error**

MySql statement Error: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
SQL: insert into form values('danish','122016','danish.baksh@hyperquality.com','devloper','marketing','danish baksh','danish.baksh@hyperquality.com','156','fdjfj','564','fjf','867','dfj','5344','contactus.png','0')

---

**query**

```
$qry="insert into form values('$empname','$empcode','$empemail','$designation','$process','$supervisior','$supemail','$expense1','$aboutexp1','$expense2','$aboutexp2','$expense3','$aboutexp3','$total','$file_name','0')";
```

---

**here is the database**

```
CREATE TABLE `form` (
 `empname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `empcode` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `empemail` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `designation` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `process` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supervisior` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supemail` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expense1` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aboutexp1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expense2` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aboutexp2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expense3` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aboutexp3` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bill` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `approved` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**ask if u need more**

Comment: You should have primary key in your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below query:

```
$qry="insert into form (empname,empcode,empemail,designation,process, supervisior,supemail,expense1,aboutexp1,expense2,aboutexp2,expense3, aboutexp3,total,bill,approved)
values('$empname','$empcode','$empemail','$designation','$process','$supervisior','$supemail','$expense1','$aboutexp1','$expense2','$aboutexp2','$expense3','$aboutexp3','$total','$file_name','0')";
```

It may help. Moreover, You should have primary key in your table.